# Row Grouping in ActionColumn in Yii2 GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I'm newbie in yii2. Grouping options are working properly in field column. But i need grouping in actionColumn in yii2 gridview.
[image]

I want to show a single button for multiple row which has common attribute value. 
My table data:

```
details_table:
id    parent_id    name
1       1          One
2       1          Two
3       2          Three
4       2          Four
```

I created url using parent id as like domain?parent_id=1. So I want to display Single button for row 1 and 2. And for 3 and 4.

```
<?php
    $gridColumns = [
        [
            'attribute' => 'date',
            'label' => 'Requisition Date',
            'value' =>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return date("d-M-Y",strtotime($model->date));
            },
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
            'width' => '10%',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'invoice_no',
            'label' => 'Invoice No',
            'width' => '10%',
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
            'group' => true,
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'depo_id',
            'label' => 'Depo Name',
            'width' => '10%',
            'value' =>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return Depo::getDepoName($model->depo_id);
            },
            'filterType'=> GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Depo::find()->orderBy('depo_name')->asArray()->all(),'id','depo_name'),
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
            'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Depo'],
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'expected_received_date',
            'label' => 'Expected Received Date',
            'value' =>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return date("d-M-Y",strtotime($model->expected_received_date));
            },
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
            'width' => '10%',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'model_id',
            'label' => 'Product Name',
            'width' => '10%',
            'value' =>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                return Prodmodels::getProductName($model->model_id);
            },
            'filterType'=> GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Prodmodels::find()->orderBy('model_name')->asArray()->all(),'id','model_name'),
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
            'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Product'],
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'qty',
            'label' => 'qty(Crtn/Bag)',
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
            'width' => '10%',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'label' => 'Status',
            'width'=>'10%',
            'value' =>function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                if($model->status==1){
                    return "Approved";
                }else if($model->status==2){
                    return "Canceled";
                }else{
                    return "New";
                }
            },
            'filterType'=> GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            /*ArrayHelper::map(Proditems::find()->orderBy('item_name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'item_name')*/
            'filter'=>array(0=>'New',1=>'Approved',2=>'Canceled'),
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
            'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Status'],
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
        ],
        [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}',
            'width' => '10%',
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'center',
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::button('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>', ['id' => 'btnShow' . $model->id, 'value' => $url, 'class' => 'btnView btn btn-sm margin-right-5px btn-success', 'title' => 'View']);
                },
                'update' => function ($url, $model) {
                    //return Html::button('<i class="fa fa-eye"></i>', ['id' => 'btnShow' . $model->id, 'value' => $url, 'class' => 'btnView btn btn-sm btn-success margin-right-5px', 'title' => 'View']);
                    return Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>', $url, ['class' => 'btn btn-sm margin-right-5px btn-success', 'title' => 'Update Depo Requisition']);
                },
                'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>', $url, [
                                'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Delete'),
                                'class' => 'btn btn-sm margin-right-5px btn-danger',
                                'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to Delete?'),
                                'data-method' => 'post',
                    ]);
                },
            ],
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                if ($action === 'view') {
                    return $url = \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['module/supplychain/csr/view', 'csr_no' => $model->csr_no]);
                }
                if ($action === 'update') {
                    return $url = \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['module/supplychain/csr/update', 'csr_no' => $model->csr_no]);
                }
                if ($action === 'delete') {
                    return $url = \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['module/supplychain/csr/delete', 'csr_no' => $model->csr_no]);
                }
            }
        ]
    ];
    ?>
    <?=GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'toolbar' => [
            ['content' =>
                Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'title' => 'Create Depo Requisition', 'id' => 'modelButton']) . ' ' .
                Html::a('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>', ['index'], ['data-pjax' => 0, 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'title' => 'reset grid'])
            ],
            '{export}',
            '{toggleData}',
        ],
        'panel' => [
            'heading' => '<div class="data-heading">Depo Requisition Info</div>',
            'type' => 'success',
            'before' => \Yii::$app->session->getFlash('flashMessage'),
            'headingOptions' => [
                'class' => 'panel-heading'
            ]
        ],
        'bordered' => true,
        'hover' => true,
        'responsive' => true,
        'condensed' => true,
    ]); ?>
```

Comment: you don't have to always use ActionColumn, you can create your own with `'group' => true` and return a url link for the whole grouping.